# BeautifulSoup filtering tags based on class value

Tags: beautifulsoup

The HTML code I get from BeautifulSoup looks a little like this:

```
<tr class="A">
    [various content]
</tr>
<tr class="B">
    [various content]
</tr>
<tr class="C">
    [various content]
</tr>
...
<tr class="NOT WANTED">
    [various content]
</tr>
...
<tr class="A">
    [various content]
</tr>
<tr class="B">
    [various content]
</tr>
<tr class="C">
    [various content]
</tr>
```

Say I want to save the code in a variable x, but without the tr tag with the unwanted class in the middle. How would I get about doing it?

I know I can do

```
x = whatever.findAll('tr', {'class' : 'A'})
```

if I just want class A, but how do I include every tr tag except the one with the "NOT WANTED" class value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with css selectors and use the [`decompose()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose):

```
soup = bs(whatever,'html.parser')
target = soup.select_one('tr[class="NOT WANTED"]')
target.decompose()
soup
```

Output should be your expected output.